# PL/SQL oracle, test window using date and time

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql

I have a function that returns a date (actual a timestamp, date+time).
In the table it looks like this, "2010-09-05 17:33:00".
when i call my function from an sql script like,

```
select my_package.my_function('2010-09-05') 
  from dual.
```

I'll get time in the result.

But if I run the same in a test window I'll only receive the date and not the time.

How could this be?

Comment: probably just the way the tool formats dates. Try to_char with an explicit date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are seeing the effect of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting. set that as required. eg:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT="yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss";
select my_package.my_function('2010-09-05') from dual;
```

to see the output properly.

or TO_CHAR the output.

```
select to_char(my_package.my_function('2010-09-05'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual;
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by test window?

If you mean SQL+ then there will be a format applied, you can change this using

```
alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Do this at the start of your SQL+ session.

Answer (score 0):

when i simply write **ALTER** .... then i get error working in procedure. However, i added below script, it worked for me.

```
execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS''';
```